# MySQL INSERT query works in Phpmyadmin but not in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Very strange.  I can't see what's going wrong here.  The connection to the MySQL database has been made but it won't INSERT from PHP.  It's fine if I run the query in Phpmyadmin.

```
$rawquery = "
    INSERT INTO $log_table_name
        (ref, timestamp, txn_id, email, item_name, item_number, custom, mc_gross, mc_currency, paypal_message)
    VALUES
        (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$txn_id', '$payer_email', '$item_name', '$item_number', '$custom', '$payment_amount', '$payment_currency', 'INVALID');
";
echo $rawquery;
$query = mysql_query($link, $rawquery) or die('Could not access table');
```

Produces:

```
INSERT INTO wp_ipn_log
    (ref, timestamp, txn_id, email, item_name, item_number, custom, mc_gross, mc_currency, paypal_message)
VALUES
    (NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'INVALID');Could not access table
```

I'm expecting the INVALID message, I just want it to be inserted into the database.

Is the problem the format of the query, or is there an issue with the database, or something else?

ADDITIONAL INFO (as requested by vinodadhikary):

```
$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die ("Could not open db ".mysql_error());
```

This is working fine.

Comment: check if the username and password are correct and have permission to write to the table

Comment: Warning: mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.Please don't use `mysql` to develop new code.

Comment: Try using `mysqli` isntead.

Comment: It was `mysqli` originally but it didn't work so I tried `mysql` instead.  Same results.

Comment: @bansi.  How do I check username and password have permission to write to the table from within phpmyadmin please?

Comment: Can you post the block where you're initializing `$link`.

Comment: add [`mysql_error()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)/[`mysqli_error($link)`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to your `die()`. Also, `mysql_query` is [`mysql_query(query, link)`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), where `mysqli_query` is [`mysql_query(link, query)`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). So it should be `$query = mysql_query($rawquery,$link) or die(mysql_error());` OR using `mysqli` -> `$query = mysqli_query($link, $rawquery) or die(mysqli_error($link));`

Comment: Thanks Sean, that was the problem - I had the $link and $rawquery the wrong way around.  Doh!  If you make it an answer, I'll accept.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When trying to debug code, it is helpful to use [`mysql_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php)/[`mysqli_error($link)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) in your `die()` rather than a generic string - `die('Could not access table')`.

Also, the order of query/link in mysql/mysqli is not the same

`mysql_query` is [`mysql_query(query,link)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), so your code should be

```
$query = mysql_query($rawquery,$link) or die(mysql_error());
```

while `mysqli_query` is [`mysqli_query(link, query)`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), so your code should be

```
$query = mysqli_query($link, $rawquery) or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to check few things on this,

1 - is NULL allowed for ref field name ? 
2 - paypal_message check is this varchar or text and check length also in database ? 
3 - can you try removing '' from each values. 
4 - last check empty is allowed ?

you can try doing with some sample values instead of empty. check if that query works, so you can go near around to solution.

Hope these things helped you

thanks